# Function to format and add object to array not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component has a state array "bets" consisting of bet objects. The function in question creates an empty "records" array to house formatted records to be stored in the database.

```js
    const placeBets = () => {
        //determine type of bet(s) - single,parlay,etc.
        if(slipType === "single"){
            let records = [];
            bets.forEach(bet=>{
                let tmpModel = formatSingleBet(bet)
                records.push(tmpModel);
            })
           console.log(records);
        }
    }
```

I run a for each loop on the bets array to format each bet calling the formatSingleBet function.

```js
    //Function to format single bets in records for db storage
    const formatSingleBet = (bet) =>{
        
        //create instance of bet model obj and add properties
        let betModel = model;
        
        betModel.type = slipType;
        betModel.wager = bet.wager;
        betModel.odds = bet.odds.decimal;
        betModel.result = "";

        let legType = bet.type;
        if(legType === "Spread"){
            //create instance of spread line object
            let spread = Spread; 
            spread.team.type = bet.team.type;
            spread.team.name = bet.team.name;
            spread.line = bet.handicap;
            spread.result = "";
            betModel.legs[0].fixtureID = bet.fixtureID; 
            betModel.legs[0].line = spread;
            betModel.legs[0].odds = bet.odds.decimal;
        }else if(legType === "3-Way Moneyline"){
            //create instance of ML line object
            let ml = ML; 
            ml.team.type = bet.team.type;
            ml.team.name = bet.team.name;
            ml.result = "";
            betModel.legs[0].fixtureID = bet.fixtureID; 
            betModel.legs[0].line = ml;
            betModel.legs[0].odds = bet.odds.decimal;        
        }else if(legType === "Total"){
            //create instance of Total line object
            let total = Total; 
            total.result = "";
            total.bet = bet.bet;
            total.line = bet.total;
            betModel.legs[0].fixtureID = bet.fixtureID; 
            betModel.legs[0].line = total;
            betModel.legs[0].odds = bet.odds.decimal;
        }

        return {
            contestPlayerID: match.params.entryid,
            jsonBet: betModel
        };
    }
```

I create an instance of the model object, and set the properties depending on the "leg type" of the bet. I then return the formatted bet to be inserted into the records array which is then returned.

The issue is that regardless of the differences in the bet, the betModel object is always returned as the last bet in the bets array.

One thing I noticed is that when I log the betModel it appears to be different for each bet, however the property values change when drilling into the object. [image]

Please help, any advice would be wonderful.

Comment: Is model an object? Is so you aren't declaring an instance of it but referencing it. To make a copy of it use spread syntax `let betModel = {...model}`.

Comment: You're a life saver. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By assigning `betModel = model` you are simply creating a reference to `model` and all the changes you make to `betModel` will also be made to `model`. This means that `model` is not a blank prototype, but contains the values of the last bet that you processed.

In order to use `model` as a prototype in the way you seem to intend use spread syntax to assign a copy to `betModel`.

```
let betModel = {...model}
```

```js
const spreadSource = { a: 1, b: 2 };

const spread = {...spreadSource};
spread.c = 'Added'
console.log('spread: ', spread);
console.log('spreadSource: ', spreadSource);

const referenceSource = { a: 1, b: 2 };

const reference = referenceSource;
reference.c = 'Added';
console.log('reference: ', reference)
console.log('referenceSource: ', referenceSource)
```